# creating tags like stackoverflow using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arraylist

i want to make tag like stack overflow tags but the problems are 1- when i click tab it doesn't work 2-when i click enter the effect of save client is clicked and 3- i want to send the tags as array of list

```
<div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                  <label>Address *</label>
                  <div class="target" contenteditable="true"></div>
                    <input type="text" id="clientAdd" name="address" value="" class="form-control required">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-3d btn-teal btn-xlg btn-block margin-top-30">
                Save Client
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
```

this is the jq code

```
$("#clientAdd").keypress(function (e) {
if (e.which === 9 || e.which === 32 ) {
     $(".target").append("<a href='#' class='tag'>" + this.value + "</a>");
        var stringList = [];
        stringList.push(this.value);
        this.value = "";
}
```

});

this is the css code

```
.tag {
 color: #3E6D8E;
 background-color: #E0EAF1;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #b3cee1;
 border-right: 1px solid #b3cee1;
 padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
 margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 90%;
 line-height: 2.4;
 white-space: nowrap;
 }
.tag:hover {
   background-color: #c4dae9;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #c4dae9;
   border-right: 1px solid #c4dae9;
}
```

Comment: You dont show any effort of your own about the 3 questions, basic what your asking is for us to code it.

Comment: There are numerous scripts around that can do this for you. Your main issue is initializing a new array in each keypress event

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen i solved most of the problems but the only one which i didn't is i want to create array of strings of the tags to send when i click on save client btn

Answer (score 1):

Use vanilla.js it's available in all browsers, it's faster and no library required. Select your elements, add an event listener, create a new element and append that element and you are done!

```js
var input = document.getElementById('clientAdd');
var target= document.getElementsByClassName('target')[0];
var button = document.querySelectorAll('button[type="submit"]')[0];
var stringList=[];

input.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){

if (e.which === 9 || e.which === 32 ){
let atag= document.createElement('a');
atag.setAttribute('class','tag');
atag.setAttribute('href','#');
atag.innerHTML=this.value;
stringList.push(this.value);
target.appendChild(atag); 
console.log('your string has been added to the array', stringList);
}
});

button.addEventListener('click', clicked =>{
let atag= document.createElement('a');
atag.setAttribute('class','tag');
atag.setAttribute('href','#');
atag.innerHTML=input.value;
stringList.push(input.value);
target.appendChild(atag); 
console.log('your string has been added to the array', stringList);
});
```

```css
.tag {
 color: #3E6D8E;
 background-color: #E0EAF1;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #b3cee1;
 border-right: 1px solid #b3cee1;
 padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
 margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 90%;
 line-height: 2.4;
 white-space: nowrap;
 }
.tag:hover {
   background-color: #c4dae9;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #c4dae9;
   border-right: 1px solid #c4dae9;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                  <label>Address *</label>
                  <div class="target" contenteditable="true"></div>
                    <input type="text" id="clientAdd" name="address" value="" class="form-control required">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-3d btn-teal btn-xlg btn-block margin-top-30">
                Save Client
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
```